# Locating image src and alt in a specific class with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find image `alt` and `src` on a webpage. But, I am only interested in the image `alt` and `src` in a certain `class`. I don't want to locate images in other classes.

Here is the `html`:

```
<div class="the class I want">
    <img alt="this is the alt I need" src="https://somesite.com/images/image.jpg" width="200" height="200">
</div>
```

Below is a Selenium code that works to locate **all** the images on the page; but, as I mentioned, I only need the images in one particular class.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.somesite.com/somepage')
image_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img")

for image in image_elements:
    img_src = image.get_attribute("src")
    alt = image.get_attribute("alt")
```

I am trying to locate the images in the `class="the class I want"` only.

Here is what I tried:

```
image_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'the class I want')]")
```

*and...*

```
image_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.the.class.I.want")
```

*Also, please note that the class name contains spaces, as indicated above.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below line:

```
image_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='the class I want']/img")
```

This should return only images that are children of `div` with required `@class`

Comment: @JoeT.Boka I prefer using xpath inspecting and then by right click and copy pasting the same so that there is chance of such mistake.